AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
I'm experiencing an inconsistency between the behavior of my unit tests and the actual functionality of a JavaScript function, ConvertHandler.getNum, within a unit conversion application.
Problem Description:
My unit test convertHandler.getNum should return an error on a double-fraction input is designed to assert that the getNum function throws an error with the message "invalid number" when provided with an input like "3/2/3 mi", which contains a double fraction. However, while running the test suite, the error is not being thrown as expected.
convertHandler should correctly return an error on a double-fraction (i.e. 3/2/3).
So, when I manually input "3/2/3 mi" in the browser frontend, the application does display the correct error message "invalid number". This discrepancy between the behavior of the unit test and the frontend interaction raises questions about the accuracy of my unit tests or potential issues with the environment.
Why the unit test fails to throw the expected error while the frontend interaction produces the correct error message ?
controllers\convertHandler.js:
function regexSplit(input) {
  const matches = input.match(/([.\d\/]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)/g);

  const number = matches
    ? matches.find((match) => /[.\d\/]+/.test(match))
    : "1";
  const string = matches
    ? matches.find((match) => /[a-zA-Z]+/.test(match))
    : "";

  return [number, string];
}

function onlyOneDiv(input) {
  let fractionParts = input.split("/");
  if (fractionParts.length > 2) {
    return false;
  }
  return fractionParts;
}

function ConvertHandler() {
  this.getNum = function (input) {
    const number = regexSplit(input)[0] || "1"; // if nothing is provided it will default to 1.

    const fractionArray = onlyOneDiv(number);

    if (isNaN(parseFloat(fractionArray[0])) || isNaN(parseFloat(fractionArray[1] || "1"))) {
      return "invalid number";
    }

    return parseFloat(fractionArray[0]) / parseFloat(fractionArray[1] || "1");
  };
}

module.exports = ConvertHandler;

tests\1_unit-tests.js:
const chai = require("chai");
let assert = chai.assert;
const ConvertHandler = require("../controllers/convertHandler.js");
let convertHandler = new ConvertHandler();

suite("Unit Tests", function () {
  test("convertHandler.getNum should return an error on a double-fraction input", function () {
    assert.throw(() => convertHandler.getNum("3/2/3 mi"), "invalid number");
  });
});

Running test returns error in terminal:

convertHandler.getNum should return an error on a double-fraction input:

AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error


In browser, code displays the error "invalid number" when i enter the value: "3/2/3 mi" :

Update: If i use assert.strictEqual or assert.equal instead of asset.throw, the unit test throws error:

AssertionError: expected [Function] to equal 'invalid number'


You do not throw "invalid number". You return it.

The issue is that assert.throw() expects a function to throw an error. Your function throws no errors, ever. It simply returns values, one of them being "invalid number" in case the input is a double fraction. To solve the problem you can do one of two things: make your function throw an actual error, or change the test to verify that the function returns the string "invalid number".

logic, but my test says that "If the number is invalid, returned will be 'invalid number'." instead of "throw error 'invalid number'"

so if i change return "invalid number" to throw "invalid number";, the test will be fine but the "If the number is invalid, returned will be 'invalid number'." will fail

Please read my answer carefully. I gave you two options. If you have an additional requirement to return "invalid number" instead of throwing an error, you should have said so explicitly in the question. With that requirement, the option of throwing an error obviously will not work, so you need to change the test to not use assert.throw() and instead verify that the value returned by the function is "invalid number", as I explained.

Solution is to change assert.throw to assert.equal or assert.strictEqual and remove the typo () =>
